# fflush - how to check if last operation was output operation

Tags: c++, c

From std::fflush documentation(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush):

> Causes the output file stream to be synchronized with the actual
>   contents of the file. The behavior is undefined if the given stream is
>   of the input type or if the given stream is of the update type, but
>   the last I/O operation was not an output operation.

I need to call fflush on a file to be able to get its size on disk, but I don't know if the last operation was input or output. Is there a way to check if the last operation on a FILE was output operation in order to prevent undefined behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/):

> In files open for update (i.e., open for both reading and writting), the stream shall be flushed after an output operation before performing an input operation. **This can be done either by repositioning (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) or by calling explicitly fflush**

Then IMO you should simply avoid to call `fflush` (even if it *should* be safe for a file open for I/O) and use `fseek` to move cursor.